# How do I change the port number for connecting to PostgreSQL via micro-orm?

Tags: postgresql, mikro-orm

While creating migration via the CLI command `npx mikro-orm migration:create`, it throws the error:

`MikroORM failed to connect to database test on postgresql://postgres@127.0.0.1:5432`

As you can see it tries to connect to port number 5432 which is the default port number given while setting up PostgreSQL but I had changed that port number to 5000 while setting up PSQL on my system.

How do I make MikroORM connect to port 5000?

Comment: add port number to mikro-orm config export

Comment: I was able to avoid this problem by changing the port number from the `postgresql.config` file, but still, I could not find a way to solve this without changing the port number to the default of 5432.

Comment: I know it's mikro but you still need to set up your database details in [init](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/installation/) to build MikroORM cli app.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [docs](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/configuration#connection). You are looking for the `port` option.